# Join created table under condition

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am creating a code to join two different tables under a certain condition. The tables look like this

```
(TABLE 2)
date | deal_code | originator   | servicer | random |
-----------------------------------------------------
2011 |    001    | commerzbank  |   SPV1   |  1     |
2012 |    001    | commerzbank  |   SPV1   |  12    |
2013 |    001    | commerzbank  |   SPV1   |  7     |
2013 |    005    | unicredit    |   SPV2   |  7     |
```

and another table

```
(TABLE 1)
date | deal_code | amount |
---------------------------
2011 |    001    | 100    |
2012 |    001    | 100    |
2013 |    001    | 100    |
2013 |    005    | 200    |
```

I would like to have this as the final result

```
date | deal_code | amount | originator   | servicer | random |
--------------------------------------------------------------
2013 |    001    | 100    | commerzbank  |   SPV1   |  7     |
2013 |    005    | 200    | unicredit    |   SPV2   |  7     |
```

I created the following code

```
select q1.deal_code, q1.date
from table1 q1  
where q1.date = (SELECT MAX(t4.date)
             FROM table1 t4 
             WHERE t4.deal_code = q1.deal_code)
```

that gives me:

```
(TABLE 3)
date | deal_code | amount |
---------------------------
2013 |    001    | 100    |
2013 |    005    | 200    |
```

That is the latest observation for table 1, now I would like to have the originator and servicer information given the deal_code and date. Any suggestion? I hope to have been clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Great job posting data as text so others can use it. I don't understand what you want as output here. Can you explain what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Sean, I would like to have the table after the sentence "I would like to have this as the final result"

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for. Please be careful when naming columns. Date is a reserved word and is too ambiguous to be a good name for a column.

```
declare @Something table
(
    SomeDate int
    , deal_code char(3)
    , originator varchar(20)
    , servicer char(4)
    , random int
)

insert @Something values
(2011, '001', 'commerzbank', 'SPV1', 1)
, (2012, '001', 'commerzbank', 'SPV1', 12)
, (2013, '001', 'commerzbank', 'SPV1', 7)
, (2013, '005', 'unicredit  ', 'SPV2', 7)

declare @SomethingElse table
(
    SomeDate int
    , deal_code char(3)
    , amount int
)

insert @SomethingElse values
(2011, '001', '100')
, (2012, '001', '100')
, (2013, '001', '100')
, (2013, '005', '200')

select x.SomeDate
    , x.deal_code
    , x.originator
    , x.servicer
    , x.random
    , x.amount
from
(
    select s.SomeDate
        , s.deal_code
        , s.originator
        , s.servicer
        , s.random
        , se.amount
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by s.deal_code order by s.SomeDate desc)
    from @Something s
    join @SomethingElse se on se.SomeDate = s.SomeDate and se.deal_code = s.deal_code
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this would work:

```
DECLARE @MaxYear INT;

SELECT @MaxYear = MAX(date)
FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
        ON t1.deal_code = t2.deal_code;

SELECT t1.date,
       t1.deal_code,
       t1.amount,
       t2.originator,
       t2.servicer,
       t2.random
FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
        ON t1.date = @MaxYear
           AND t1.deal_code = t2.deal_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sean Lange about the `date` column name. His method gets around the dependency on the correlated sub-query, but at the heart of things, you really just need to add an `INNER JOIN` to your existing query in order to get the `amount` column into your result set.

```
select 
  q2.date,
  q2.deal_code, 
  q1.amount,
  q2.originator,    
  q2.servicer,  
  q2.random
from 
  table1 q1  
  join
  table2 q2
    on q1.date = q2.date
    and q1.deal_code = q2.deal_code
where q1.date = (SELECT MAX(t4.date)
             FROM table1 t4 
             WHERE t4.deal_code = q1.deal_code)
```